# To grep version number from Wordpress plugin folder

Tags: regex, grep, wordpress

What will be grep regex to extract version number like

```
 Version: 3.1.5
 * Version: 3.1.5
```

Will output   **3.1.5**

But It should not catch likes

```
MIME-Version: 1.0\n
```

Here is my grep command

```
grep -ri 'version\s*:\s*[0-9\.]\w*' /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/plugin_name
```

@anubhava
`woocommerce` is a folder. There is file `woocommerce.php` under this folder.

**Content of `woocommerce.php` **

```
 * Plugin Name: WooCommerce
 * Plugin URI: http://www.woothemes.com/woocommerce/
 * Description: An e-commerce toolkit that helps you sell anything. Beautifully.
 * Version: 2.3.8
 * Author: WooThemes
 * Author URI: http://woothemes.com
 * Requires at least: 4.0
 * Tested up to: 4.2
```

**Working**

```
grep -rPo "(^|\s|^\*)+(Version\s*:\s*)\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -rPo "(^|\s|^\*)+(Version\s*:\s*)\K([0-9]|\.)*(?=\s|$)" /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/attachments/
```

**Explanation :**

- `-P` stands for PCRE, `-o` for taking only the matched portion of the line
- `(^|\s)+(Version: )` will match `Version` at the start or one or more whitespaces, the `\K` will then discard the match
- `([0-9]|\.)*` will match any digit or `.` zero or more times, this is what we want
- The previous token will be followed by either any whitespace character or end of the line

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -oP` (PERL style regex):

```
grep -oP 'Version: *\K\S+' file
3.1.5
3.1.5
```

`Version: *` matches literal `Version:` followed by 0 or more spaces. `\K` resets the match information and `\S+` matches version number.

Comment: it isn't working on folder search. I want to grep insider plugin folder with maxdepth of 1.

Comment: What is folder search in `grep`? Can you show content of `plugin_name` in your question.

Comment: `grep -oP 'Version: *\K\S+' /home/test/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce`

Comment: I need to see content of `woocommerce` to check why is this grep not working for you.

Comment: I have update question with content of `woocommerce`

Comment: `grep -oP 'Version: *\K\S+' woocommerce` is giving me `2.3.8` from above content. What are you getting?